# SQLite C++ query rows - how to handle multiple columns

Tags: c++, sql, database, sqlite, c++11

I'm new to SQLite, C++ and having some trouble understanding how one deals with multiple rows returned from a query. I need to put the value of each column int a variable so I can deal with it later.

I have so far:

```
sqlite3_stmt* statement;

if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(getDatabase(), _sql.c_str(), -1, &statement, 0)
            == SQLITE_OK)
{
    int cols = sqlite3_column_count(statement);
    int result = 0;

    while(true)
    {
        result = sqlite3_step(statement);

        if(result == SQLITE_ROW)
        {
             for(int col = 0; col < cols; col++)
             {
                // go through each column and store it       
             }
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

so what do I do in my `for` loop?

```
if (col == 0) // first column position
{
   // store it...
}
else if (col == 1) // second column position
{
    // store it...
}
```

or is there a way to do it by column name?

or is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: What's the end goal? After the loop is complete, where exactly do you want the data to end up, and what do you want to do with it next? Re: column names - see `sqlite3_column_name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

The correct procedure is to loop through each row and use `sqlite_column(statement, [col#])`